# Como agregar progressBar por código en android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo que implementar muchos progressbar en mi aplicación, la solución que utilizo es en cada archivo **XML**

```
                   <ProgressBar
                   android:id="@+id/circular_indicator"
                   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:indeterminate="true"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:indeterminateTint="@color/secondary"
                   android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Y en su Activity o Fragment correspondiente

```
 // relacionado con el XML
 binding.circularIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Y quiero algo similar a un objeto ProgressBar de modo que en solo haya que modificar la Activity o Fragment

```
// 1º Crear objeto circularIndicator de la clase ProgressBar
// 2º Mostrarlo
      circularIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta o por qué quieres crear la PB por código ¿? ¿No es mejor tenerla definida en un XML y hacer `include` en los XML (layout) de los fragmentos donde la necesites? ¿O es que son diferentes PB, con estilos/tipos distintos? En ese caso crea una PB con cada tipo/estilo y usas `include` igualmente. O, si la PB debe ser modificada según qué contextos lo mismo, puedes ponerla con `include` y luego modificarla de forma programática si hiciera falta.

Comment: Gracias, esa es la idea que necesitaba "¿No es mejor tenerla definida en un XML y hacer include en los XML (layout) de los fragmentos donde la necesites? " quería "centralizar" y definirla una sola vez

Comment: Pues ese sería el mejor modo, . Dicho eso, ¿cuál es el problema? Para comprender cómo funciona include, [revisa la doc de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts), luego haz un intento y si no funcionas nos dices.

Comment: Para crearla solo por código tenes que usar jetpack compose

Comment: Siguiendo la sugerencia de @A.Cedano; la utilización de include evita la repetición de definir el PB en cada activity, que era lo que quería consegir